# How to pass Jenkins credentials to a Dockerfile/Shell?

Tags: shell, docker, jenkins, arguments, credentials

I've a Makefile with:

```
docker build --build-arg USER=${USER} --build-arg PASSWD=${PASSWD}
```

and I build it in a jenkins script with:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'my-credentials', passwordVariable: 'PASSWD', usernameVariable: 'USER')]) { (build_step) }
```

In a Dockerfile script, I have:

```
ARG USER

ARG PASSWD 

curl -u ${USER}:${PASSWD}
```

Where USER/PASSWD pair is passed to repo/API.

What are necessary steps for USER / PASSWD to be passed properly? I've tried a lot of solutions/syntax options and RUN export. None seems to be working.

Is there a way to RUN echo variables from dockerfile? Jenkins log shows either a variable name or whitespaces for most of attempts.

Comment: WORKAROUND: Removed Makefile / withCredidentials step. Credidentials in curl step were replaced by credidentials of a default, public REST api user.

Comment: POSSIBLE SOLUTION/INVALID PROBLEM STATEMENT: I had a FROM instruction after ARGs. If ARGs are replaced after FROM, code might be working. Based on:  https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34129 "Basically, after the FROM instruction all the build arguments are reset and thus aren't available in the Dockerfile."

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the arguments to dockerile using `--build-arg`. So in this case you could run something like `docker build --build-arg USER=${USER} --build-arg PASSWD=${PASSWD}`

Comment: Build step is 'make -C my_dir build id=$id', where id was defined in jenkins environment. Isn't a Makefile already passing these arguments (see: First line of code)?  From a console output, it appears that this step is being executed, since jenkins credentials are concealed by **** (--build-arg USER=**** --build-arg PASSWD=****) but a further investigation shows them as empty.